# Elasticsearch Positive vs Negative Queries - Is it possible?

Tags: elasticsearch, nlp

This may be far fetched but can someone let me know if and how it would be possible to run the following type of query in elasticsearch.

I have an index of documents with product descriptions in a 'description' field. This includes free form text that describes what a product is used for. I want to search for all products that have positive search results. By positive I can provide the following example "valid for use by children under 7 years old". A negative search result would be the following "not valid for use by children under 7 years old". Is there someway that I can use elasticsearch to natively differentiate between these positive and negative searches so I can only return products that are positive? If so how can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at this [blog post](http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/quick-tips-negative-connotation-filter/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes -- you can negate a query... you could also stucture your data so that `"age": 7` was part of your data and then do a

```
"bool": {  
    "must": {  
        "range" : {
            "age" : {
                "gte" : 7
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can easily negate the bool query by changing `must` to `must_not`.

Comment: I believe OP was trying to do this using some sort of NLP since his data is textual and not structured. Hence there is no 'Age' facet.